# What is the unit of information as defined by information theory?

Tags: units, probability, information

It appears to be defined by probability; however, does it have some unit that indicates its 'information level' in terms of probability?

Comment: Did you even search for [units of information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_information) beforehand?

Comment: a nybble is a unit of information. A nybble is half a byte.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I'm searching for a unit of information as defined by information theory.

Comment: some speak about half-bits but it is another thing. Simply the bit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which logarithm you choose. To demonstrate (but not prove) the information theory equation: the definition $S = \log W$ (uncertainty is the logarithm of multiplicity, Boltzmann's famous relation) becomes equivalent, if $p_i = 1/W$ ($W$ equally probable outcomes) to $$S = -\sum_{i=1}^W p_i \log p_i.$$But since $\log_a(b) = \log_c(b) / \log_c(a)$ we are always a multiplicative constant away from choosing whatever base we want.

The easiest way, common in computer science circles, is to choose the base-2 logarithm. Then the uncertainty is measured in **bits**, and so is *information* (which is a reduction in uncertainty).

So if you have a system with ten distinguishable coins, there are 1024 possible outcomes and all of them are equally probable. If you know nothing more about the system, then your uncertainty is $\log_2 1024 = \text{10 bits}$. Someone needs to send you 10 bits to tell you what state the system is in. But if you have a system with ten *indistinguishable* coins, there are only 11 different possible outcomes (none are heads up, one is heads up, ... all ten are heads up) which we could easily encode as a 4-bit number. Information theory says that these various probabilities corresponding to the distribution of `[1,10,45,120,210,252,210,120,45,10,1]` allow us to reduce the problem to $-\sum_i p_i \log_2 p_i = 2.706\dots\text{ bits}$. Probably to actually attain this you'd need a "lossy compression" and you'd evaluate how good it is with a "square-root of the sum of squared errors" in what it reproduces, but the simplest case is to round 0, 1, and 2 to 2, and 10 to 9, and then you're typically only off by 0.34.